# Implementing Merge Sort in C++ using Vectors

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I wanted to do an implementation of Merge Sort in C++. I didn't look at concrete examples because I wanted to try out for myself. And here is what I came up with using vectors:

```
int *mergeSort(int *a, int n) {
    //some debugging info for me
    cout << "Merge Sort called with: ";

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << *(a + i) << " ";
    }

    cout << " and size: " << n << endl;

    //base case
    if (n == 1) {
        return a;
    }

    //spliting the arrays
    vector<int> firstArray(a, a + n/2);
    vector<int> secondArray(a + n/2, a + n);


    int *firstResultPointer = mergeSort(&(firstArray[0]), firstArray.size());
    vector<int> resultFirst(firstResultPointer, firstResultPointer + n/2);

    int *secondResultPointer = mergeSort(&(secondArray[0]), secondArray.size());
    vector<int>resultSecond(secondResultPointer, secondResultPointer + n / 2);

    vector<int> resultArray(n);

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (i + j < n) {
        //when exit the size of the vector
        if(firstArray.size() <= i){
            while(j < secondArray.size()){
                resultArray[(i + j)] = secondArray[j];
                j++;
            }
            break;
        }
        else if (secondArray.size() <= j){
            while(i < firstArray.size()){
                resultArray[(i + j)] = firstArray[i];
                i++;
            }
            break;
        }
        else {
            //normal case merge
            if (firstArray[i] < secondArray[j]) {
                resultArray[(i + j)] = firstArray[i];
                i++;
            }
            else {
                resultArray[(i + j)] = secondArray[j];
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

    return &(resultArray[0]);
}
```

**a** is a pointer to the vector and **n** is the length of the same vector. I had quite a lot of trouble in the merging because it would leave the vector and start using 0. I think I fixed that based on my debugging. However, when I debug after I get to the lowest level and then starting going back up it just starts jumping all over the place and I cannot follow it. Using cout I printed to see what arguments are passed to the merge sort and they seem to be correct. Can anyone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: "when I debug after I get to the lowest level and then starting going back up it just starts jumping all over the place" have you got optimizations enabled?

Comment: `mergeSort` returns a pointer to a local variable. `resultArray` is destroyed when the function returns, and the pointer becomes dangling. Your program therefore exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an object after its lifetime has ended.

Comment: Apart from the issue with the return value (which you aren't actually using for anything substantial), your `mergeSort` is a very elaborate no-op. It has no side effects. It's busy shuffling around elements in local variables, but never touches the original array.

Comment: Thanks. I just removed the resultArray variable and changed it with the original array and it worked.